# Convert all values in a csv column to integer (or remove leading zeroes) in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv file with an ID_code column and the IDs have leading zeroes that I want to remove.  I found out that if I convert the value to an integer, the leading zeroes should disappear but I don't know how to apply that to all values throughout the csv.  This is what I tried but the resulting csv comes out blank:

```
Import-Csv C:\folder\myFile.csv |
  ForEach-Object {
    $_.ID_code = [convert]::ToInt32($_.ID_code, 10)  } |
```

convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation | %{$_-replace '"', ""} |
out-file C:\folder\myFile2.csv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) for that. You don't need to parse the value, though. Simply casting it to `int` should suffice:

```psh
Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\input.csv' |
  select -Property @{n='ID_code';e={[int]$_.ID_code}},* -Exclude 'ID_code' |
  Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv'
```

Another option (since you're exporting the data back to a text file anyway) would be to just remove leading zeroes from the string value:

```psh
Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\input.csv' |
  select -Property @{n='ID_code';e={$_.ID_code -replace '^0+'}},* -Exclude 'ID_code' |
  Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv'
```

If you know the position of the `ID_code` column you don't even need to import the CSV. If for instance the column is the first column in the CSV you could do the replacement like this:

```psh
(Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.csv') -replace '^0+' |
  Set-Content 'C:\path\to\output.csv'
```