# Convert a CSV string column to integer in Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, casting

I'm trying to update a column from string to integer.

I have a `file.csv`:

```
"Numbers", "Names"
"1", "Dave"
"4", "Peter"
"8", "Holly"
```

I want to update the `Numbers` column to `int`:

```
"Numbers", "Names"
1, "Dave"
4, "Peter"
8, "Holly"
```

Is there a way to loop through the values in `Numbers` column and typecast those values to `int` then update the same `file.csv` table with the new values?

This is what I have thought of so far:

```
$csv = Import-CSV file.csv
$CountCol = $csv | Select-Object 'Numbers'
$col1 = [int]$CountCol[0]
$col2 = [int]$CountCol[1]
$col3 = [int]$CountCol[2]
```

I also thought maybe I could do a loop:

```
$colList = @($CountCol[0], $CountCol[1], $CountCol[2])
For ($i=0; $i -lt $colList.Length; $i++) {
    $col = [int]$CountCol[$i]
    $CountCol[$i], 'Names' | Export-CSV file.csv -append -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Wondering if I'm on the right track.

Comment: Anything you export to CSV is exported as a string invariantly. Seems like you're looking to export to an actual `.xlsx` file instead.

Comment: You could use a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties) for that. You don't need to parse the value, though. Simply casting it to `int` should suffice:[Convert all values in a csv column to integer (or remove leading zeroes) in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28073963/1701026)

Comment: Csv only has strings.  You could use json instead.  Or do math like `1 + $_.Numbers`

Comment: If you're just wanting to change format of the text file, you could go with a text-based approach and regular expressions: `( gc $FileName | %{ $_ -replace '"(\d+)"' , '$1'} ) | sc $FileName`

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
$csv = Import-CSV file.csv | Select @{l='Numbers';e={$_.Numbers -as [int]}},* -Exclude Numbers
```

That will create a new "Numbers" property converting the existing Numbers property to an integer, and excluding the existing Numbers property, effectively replacing it with the integer version.